# .save() instance is not working while saving the data from the JSON file(in Insomnia) to my MongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to create a new user but the data is not being saved in MongoDB Atlas. My server is successfully connected to the MongoDB Atlas and it also fetching the data from the JSON file in Insomnia.

Here is the **auth.js** file

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import User from "../models/User.js"
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs"

export const signup = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
        const newUser = new User({ ...req.body, password: hash});

        await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).send("User has been created!")
    } catch(err) {
        // todo
    }
}
```

and here is the **index.js** file

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import videoRoutes from "./routes/videos.js";
import commentRoutes from "./routes/comments.js";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js"

const app = express()
dotenv.config()

const connect = () => {
    mongoose
        .connect(process.env.MONGO)
        .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to DB")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
};

app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes)
app.use("/api/videos", videoRoutes)
app.use("/api/comments", commentRoutes)

app.listen(8800, ()=> {
    connect()
    console.log("Connected to Server")
})
```

Honestly, I can't see any error in my code but then also it is not working. Is there anyone who could kindly help with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just resolved it. It was just a silly error, I was trying to create a new user which already existed in my database. Hence the reason I was not able to fetch anything.